# What mask for a LAN with two routers / subnets?

Tags: router, ip, ip-address, subnet, mikrotik-routeros

I have a **main-router** connected to ISP and most devices connected to it.

It has IP `192.168.0.1` and it's connected clients get IPs in range of `192.168.0.X`

A **second-router** connected to this one, will have clients connected to it in range of `192.168.1.X`

I don't know if under `Network > Lan` of **first-router** I should set subnet mask as `255.255.255.0` or `255.255.0.0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subnet addressing must not overlap. If the two networks are actually separate (i.e. have their own gateways, their own DHCP servers, etc.), then you should continue using 255.255.255.0 for the first network as well.

Subnets do not actually nest – that is, devices connected to your second router's subnet *do not* automatically belong to the subnet of the first router, and the subnet mask should not indicate that they do.

(Though it is possible to create exceptions to that – e.g. "Proxy ARP" can be used to make the second router *pretend* that devices in a smaller subnet directly belong to a larger one.)

Answer (score 1):

```
255.255.255.0
```

The networks should be separate.